# index runtime field is emitting 101 values while the maximum number of values allowed is 100

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

Getting error while loading logs in Kibana dashboard.
"index runtime field is emitting 101 values while the maximum number of values allowed is 100"

Stack used:

Telegraf to send application logs to Elasticsearch

Elasticsearch (Ingest pipeline to format logs)
Kibana

### Ingest pipeline code

```
[
  {
    "remove": {
      "field": [
        "measurement_name",
        "tag.appname",
        "tag.host",
        "tag.dc",
        "tag.env",
        "tag.qcinstance",
        "tag.servergroup"
      ],
      "tag": "remove_tag_fields"
    }
  },
  {
    "json": {
      "field": "loggly_logs.msg",
      "target_field": "log_message"
    }
  },
  {
    "remove": {
      "field": "loggly_logs.msg"
    }
  },
  {
    "date": {
      "field": "log_message.timestamp",
      "formats": [
        "ISO8601"
      ],
      "target_field": "@timestamp"
    }
  }
]

using index template

{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "mapping": {
          "total_fields": {
            "limit": "1000"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "runtime"
    },
    "aliases": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your script looks like?

Comment: @Val We are not using any script, these are application logs that are being send to ES.
I have updated the question with the ingest pipeline code and the index template code we are using to format the data

Answer (score 0):

The [maximum number of values](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/8.10/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/script/AbstractFieldScript.java#L135-L147) that can be emitted from a script piloting a runtime field is 100 and that limit is not configurable for now. That check is made in [various places](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aelastic%2Felasticsearch%20checkMaxSize&type=code) and cannot be bypassed.

What you need to do is to modify your script in order to emit less values and not cross the hard limit of 100.

Comment: We are not using any script, these are application logs that are being send to ES. I have updated the question with the ingest pipeline code and the index template code we are using to format the data  @val